Pólya's orchard problem among Gaussian primes
Quoting myself from an earlier post:

Pólya's orchard problem asks for which radius $r$ of trees at each lattice point within a distance $R$ of the origin block all lines of sight to the exterior of the orchard. It has been established that rays to infinity are completely blocked iff
$r \ge  1/\sqrt{R^2 + 1}$, when $R$ is an integer.

Q. Now I pose a variation of the same question, but for trees
at each Gaussian prime.
Here's an example for $R=10$. I set the tree radius to $0.31$, but the two thin
red cones are not blocked: rays can reach beyond $R$. Increasing $r$ to
$0.332$ closes up the sliver between primes $(3,0)$ and $(6,1)$,
blocking all rays out to $R$.

I've made similar computations by overlaying on a red background
the blue blocking cones for each
prime, and gradually increasing $r$ until no underlying red cone remains.
This is a very crude calculation method, but it suggests that the $r \approx  1/R$
behavior for lattice point trees does not hold for Gaussian primes.
In fact, $r$ seems to be constant (about $0.318$) for $20 \le R \le 100$,
the limit of my calculations.
